# Select the n most frequent items from a pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I´m working on trying to get the n most frequent items from a pandas dataframe similar to

```
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
| cod| name|sum_vol|  date|   lat|   lon|
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
|aggc|23124|     37|201610|-15.42|-32.11|
|aggc|23124|     19|201611|-15.42|-32.11|
| abc|  231|     22|201610|-26.42|-43.11|
| abc|  231|     22|201611|-26.42|-43.11|
| ttx|  231|     10|201610|-22.42|-46.11|
| ttx|  231|     10|201611|-22.42|-46.11|
| tty|  231|     25|201610|-25.42|-42.11|
| tty|  231|     45|201611|-25.42|-42.11|
|xptx|  124|     62|201611|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|  124|    260|201610|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|23124|     50|201610|-26.43|-43.21|
|xptx|23124|     50|201611|-26.43|-43.21|
+----+-----+-------+------+------+------+
```

I´m able to do it using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cod':['aggc','abc'], 'name':[23124,23124],
                   'sum_vol':[37,19], 'date':[201610,201611],
                    'lat':[-15.42, -15.42], 'lon':[-32.11, -32.11]})

gg = df.groupby(['name','date']).cod.value_counts().to_frame()
gg = gg.rename(columns={'cod':'count_cod'}).reset_index()
df_top_freq = gg.groupby(['name', 'date']).head(5)
```

But this code is slow and very cumbersome. Is there a way to do it in a more flexible and straightforward way?

Comment: While the [tag:pandas] regulars will recognize the `df` abbreviation to be from `dataframe`, I'd advice you to post at least the imports with your code. Additional context will never hurt either. Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg) function allows you to calculate the frequency for each group using the standard library function `len`.
Sorting the result by the aggregated column `code_count` values, in descending order, then `head` selecting the top `n` records, then reseting the frame; will produce the top n frequent records

```
import pandas as pd
data_values = [['aggc', 23124, 37, 201610, -15.42, -32.11],
               ['aggc', 23124, 19, 201611, -15.42, -32.11],
               [' abc', 231, 22, 201610, -26.42, -43.11],
               [' abc', 231, 22, 201611, -26.42, -43.11],
               [' ttx', 231, 10, 201610, -22.42, -46.11],
               [' ttx', 231, 10, 201611, -22.42, -46.11],
               [' tty', 231, 25, 201610, -25.42, -42.11],
               [' tty', 231, 45, 201611, -25.42, -42.11],
               ['xptx', 124, 62, 201611, -26.43, -43.21],
               ['xptx', 124, 260, 201610, -26.43, -43.21],
               ['xptx', 23124, 50, 201610, -26.43, -43.21],
               ['xptx', 23124, 50, 201611, -26.43, -43.21]]
data_cols = ['cod', 'name', 'sum_vol', 'date', 'lat', 'lon']
df = pd.DataFrame(data_values, columns=data_cols)

df_top_freq = df.groupby(['date', 'name'])['cod'].agg(
    {"code_count": len}).sort_values(
    "code_count", ascending=False).head(n).reset_index()
```

The `df_top_freq` frame will look like below

```
    |    |   date |   name |   code_count |
    |----+--------+--------+--------------|
    |  0 | 201610 |    231 |            3 |
    |  1 | 201611 |    231 |            3 |
    |  2 | 201610 |  23124 |            2 |
    |  3 | 201611 |  23124 |            2 |
    |  4 | 201610 |    124 |            1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `groupby` twice unnecessarily.  Instead, define a helper function to apply with.

Also, `value_counts` by default sorts results by descending count.  So using `head` directly afterwards is perfect.

```
def top_value_count(x, n=5):
    return x.value_counts().head(n)

gb = df.groupby(['name', 'date']).cod
df_top_freq = gb.apply(top_value_count).reset_index()
df_top_freq.rename(columns=dict(level_2='cod', cod='count_cod'))
```